# Exporting All Streets in a City - Multiple Lines, With Latitude and Longitude

Tags: postgis, export, postgis-2.0

I installed Postgresql, Gis, SELECT postgis_full_version() reports,

```
 POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel.
 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16"
 LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99"
```

I was able to import data for a single city, from a Geofabrik file, through osm2pgsql.

Now I'd like to export all pedestrian streets in this database in lat,lon,name format. Same street could show up in multiple rows, a street being composed of multiple line segments - that is fine.

I am able to use this query to get streets, and I believe they are line pieces, but how do I get the latitude / longitude associated with the beginning and end of that line?

```
SELECT name FROM planet_osm_line WHERE highway in ('pedestrian');
```

What would be the simplest query to do this?

Comment: SELECT concat(ST_X(ST_StartPoint(line)) ,', ', ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(line)) FROM planet_osm_line WHERE highway in ('pedestrian'); and possibly the same for ST_EndPoint?

Comment: Or simply ST_StartPoint/ST_EndPoint if you want to extract the geometry, rather than a string representation.

Comment: Hmm.. there was no line column, but this seemed to work, st_asText(st_startpoint(st_transform(way, 4326))).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't have osm in front of me, I should have stated <geom_column>. Different osm loaders have different naming conventions

Comment: OSM is in 4326 by default, so, you shouldn't really need ST_Transform.

Comment: Without the transform I get something like POINT(1493092.82 6896824.77)..

Comment: OK, ignore me then, that looks like spherical mercator. You must have supplied some SRID switch to osm2pgsql. I use osmosis, which loads OSM in a more raw format, and is most definitely 4326.

Comment: Ah ok - maybe next time I'll run osm2pgsql so 4326 becomes the default for me as well.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A query to dump all streets with their beginning and end with lat/lon format

```
psql -d gis -t -A -F";" -c \
     "SELECT  osm_id,name,highway,\
     st_asText(st_startpoint(st_transform(way, 4326))), \
     st_asText(st_endpoint(st_transform(way, 4326))) \
     FROM planet_osm_line " > output.csv
```

The same street name can show up as multiple rows, with different osm_id's. It seemed that multiple pieces of the same street appear as different rows.